# How to disable default login box in windows universal app

Tags: windows-authentication, win-universal-app

I want to use unified UI for handling different authentication type in win10 universal app, but the default login box(windows authentication) will always be prompted when try to access some resource that need to be authenticated by Windows authentication.

Is it possible to disable the default popup login window in my UWP application?

Comment: If you are using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`, set a `HttpBaseProtocolFilter.AllowUI` to `false`. Of course, requests will fail with 401 error if you do not provide credentials.

Comment: @Kiewic, Thank you very much, this is what I want!!!